# Exclude the last delimited item from my list

Tags: python

I want to remove the last string in the list i.e. the library name (delimited by '\'). The text string that I have contains path of libraries used at the compilation time. These libraries are delimited by spaces. I want to retain each path but not till the library name, just one root before it.

Example:

```
text = " /opt/gcc/4.4.4/snos/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4.4/crtbeginT.o /opt/gcc/4.4.4/snos/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4.4/crtfastmath.o /opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64/no_mmap.o /opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64/libcraymath.a /opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64/libcraymp.a /opt/cray/atp/1.7.1/lib/libAtpSigHandler.a /opt/cray/atp/1.7.1/lib/libAtpSigHCommData.a "
```

I want my output to be like -

```
Output_list =
[/opt/gcc/4.4.4/snos/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4.4,
/opt/gcc/4.4.4/snos/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4.4,
/opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64,
/opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64, 
/opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64, 
/opt/cray/atp/1.7.1/lib,
/opt/cray/atp/1.7.1/lib]
```

and finally I want to remove the duplicates in the output_list so that the list looks like.

```
New_output_list =
[/opt/gcc/4.4.4/snos/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4.4,
/opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64,
/opt/cray/atp/1.7.1/lib]
```

I am getting the results using split() function but I am struggling to discard the library names from the path.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want (don't try and do string operations with paths, it's bound to end badly):

```
import os

New_output_List = list(set(os.path.dirname(pt) for pt in text.split()))
```

[`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) splits a path into it's gets the directory name from a path. We do this for every item in the `text`, `split` into a `list` based on white-space. This is done for every item in the series.
To remove the duplicates, we just convert it to a `set` and then finally to a `list`.

Comment: I think ```os.path.dirname()``` be a tad simpler

Comment: actually I am reading the path from a database and not getting it at run time. So I have only the text string to work on.

Comment: @user2907995 My code already deals with that by converting it into a list. It still takes the string as input.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
    text = " /opt/gcc/4.4.4/snos/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4.4/crtbeginT.o /opt/gcc/4.4.4/snos/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4.4/crtfastmath.o /opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64/no_mmap.o /opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64/libcraymath.a /opt/cray/cce/8.2.5/craylibs/x86-64/libcraymp.a /opt/cray/atp/1.7.1/lib/libAtpSigHandler.a /opt/cray/atp/1.7.1/lib/libAtpSigHCommData.a "
    New_output_List = []
    for x in list(set(text.split(' '))):
        New_output_list.append("".join("/" + y if y else '' for y in x.split("/")[:-1]))
```

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use string operations rather than built-in path functionality. This hard-coding approach will fail in many cases.